# Longitudinal changes: linear mixed effect model Vs linear model using baseline measure as covariate

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme, linear-model, ancova, clinical-trials

I am trying to study longitudinal changes in patients for measure '`a`'.
I have 2 measures of 'a' at baseline ('`a_baseline`') and at follow up ('`a_FU`').
I have also have other covariates, as `sex`, `age`, `blood pressure` etc

What would be better?

a) To express this as a **linear model** with `a_baseline` as covariate:

```
lm(a_FU ~ a_baseline + sex + age, data = df, na.action = na.omit)
```

b) To pivot the dataset so there is now only 1 column expressing `a`, and therefore every patient appears twice (ie. patient ID = 1, will have visit 1 and visit 2.)

So we would express this as a **linear mixed-effect model** as:

```
lme(a ~ sex + age + random= ~1|patient_ID, data = df, na.action = na.omit)
```

Thanks!